# Generating function for numbers divisible by some primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

Consider the first $k$ primes $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, \dots, p_k$. Let $A_k$ be the set of numbers that are divisible by at least one $p_i$. We can represent this set as a generating function:

$$G_k(x) = \sum_{t \in A_k} x^t.$$

**Example:** $G_2(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2} + \frac{1}{1-x^3} - \frac{1}{1-x^6}.$

By the inclusion-exclusion principle (as in  the previous example), any such $G_k$ can be written as a rational function. However, such a representation with inclusion-exclusion uses $2^k - 1$ terms.

**Question:** Is there any significantly shorter way to write this series $G_k(x)$ as a rational function?

Comment: $A_k$ is a finite union of arithmetic progressions with common difference $p_1 \dots p_k$, so the generating function has the form $\frac{P(x)}{1 - x^{p_1 \dots p_k}}$ for some polynomial $P(x)$. The computation of $P(x)$ is exactly the computation of the first $p_1 \dots p_k$ terms of the sequence. I don't know if that's the sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. This is true. The polynomial $P$ must contain many monomials however.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not what you look for, but you may denote $N=\prod p_i$, $m_i=N/p_i$, then consider a polynomial $$q(x)=\prod_i (x^{m_i}+x^{2m_i}+\dots+x^{(p_i-1)m_i}).$$
Your generating function equals $$\frac1{1-x}-\frac{q(x)\pmod {1-x^{N}}}{1-x^{N}}.$$

Or, if you define a fractional part of a rational function $r=f/g$ as $\{r\}=h/g$, where $h=$(remainder of $f$ modulo $g$), the answer may be rewritten as $$\frac1{1-x}-\left\{
\frac{\prod(x^{m_i}-x^N)}{(1-x^N)\prod(1-x^{m_i})}
\right\}.$$

Comment: I see. This is the g.f. for the numbers not divisible by any $p_i$.

Comment: Of course, fixed now.